# c# wpf store DataGrid collection localy and filter with Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filter, collectionview

i've created a simple wmi query and then created a custom collection.
i've added a filter that takes the string from a textbox on a text change event.
it's working as expected but with 1 major drawback, every time you try to filter it's actually doing the query all over. what i want it to do is store the collection localy and make the manipulation on that local var instead of doing the wmi query over and over.
i've tried multipile ways but no luck so far.
any help will be appriciated! :)

here's 1 way i tried...

Main cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace myfilter
{
    public partial class FilteringSample : Window
    {
        public FilteringSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myProcesses items = new myProcesses();
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = items.GetProcesses;

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
            view.Filter = UserFilter;
        }

        private bool UserFilter(object item)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilter.Text))
                return true;
            else
                return ((item as myProcess).Name.IndexOf(txtFilter.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }

        private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource).Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

class cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myfilter
{
    class myProcesses
    {
        public IEnumerable<myProcess> GetProcesses
        {
            get
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Process");
                ManagementObjectCollection processList = searcher.Get();
                myProcess myproc;
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in processList)
                {
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        myproc = new myProcess();
                        try
                        {
                            myproc.Name = obj["Name"].ToString();
                        }
                        catch { }
                        try
                        {
                            myproc.ID = obj["ProcessId"].ToString();
                        }
                        catch { }

                        yield return myproc;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class myProcess
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="myfilter.FilteringSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="FilteringSample" Height="200" Width="300">
    <DockPanel Margin="10">
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" Name="txtFilter" TextChanged="txtFilter_TextChanged" />
        <DataGrid Name="lvUsers">

        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window
```

>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well think i managed to figure it out by myself.
i stored the data in an

```
ObservableCollection<>
```

and that let me check the filter results locally and no Re-launch the query again.
so here is the modified code if anyone is interested (the change was made only within the main cs):

```
namespace filter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<myProcess> myCollection;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            myProcesses items = new myProcesses();
            myCollection = new ObservableCollection<myProcess>();
            foreach (myProcess localproc in items.GetProcesses)
            {
                myCollection.Add(localproc);
            }
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = myCollection;

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection);
            view.Filter = UserFilter;
        }

        private bool UserFilter(object item)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilter.Text))
                return true;
            else
                return ((item as myProcess).Name.IndexOf(txtFilter.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }

        private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection).Refresh();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you appear to be running into is the fact you are doing all of the work (querying WMI) on the UI (dispatcher) thread. If you want the UI to remain responsive and not 'white screen' or freeze whilst a user is using the application you are going to have to investigate using an asynchronous approach to querying for the data.

There are several parts of the .Net framework available to help you with this:

- TPL (Task<T>)
- BackgroundWorker class,
- Thread class,

Are a couple of examples, additionally there are technologies like Rx (Reactive Extensions for .Net) which encapsulate and provide a very well defined API for handling asynchronous problems.

Which ever solution you choose you will have to deal with updating the UI from a background thread, there are plenty of examples of how to do this on SO.

Of course introducing asynchronous execution into your program will generally increase the complexity of any code base, especially UI code, but this is the cost if you want your application to remain performant from a users perspective.

After all that, if you don't want to use an asynchronous approach you could just cache the results from the WMI query in the myProcesses class for a specific amount of time, lets say 1 minute, so any future request would return these result instead of doing another query and once the 1 minute has expired you would clear the cached results and a future query would execute against WMI again repeat the process again.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar to dataset on asp. for example you can query a sql server but store the tables on a dataset and do the manipulation on the dataset...